Auth0 throws an exception on MAUI Android
MAUI does not work with Auth0 on Android but works on iOS
I had added the following android specific code
using Android.Content;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;

namespace abc.Mobile;
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
              DataScheme = CALLBACK_SCHEME)]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Microsoft.Maui.Authentication.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{
    const string CALLBACK_SCHEME = "com.abc";
}

Where as this was my login code
var authenticationService = new Auth0Client(new() {
                Domain = "<YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN>",
                ClientId = Preferences.Get("ClientId", "xxx"), //Client Id from Auth0 portal
                RedirectUri = "com.abc://callback/",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "com.abc://callback/",
                Scope = "openid offline_access"
            });

authenticationResult = await authenticationService.LoginAsync(new {
                        audience = xxx, // Audience from Auth0 portal
                        prompt = "select_account"
                    });

I keep hitting this exception instead even though I have already subclassed it in the above provided code
You must subclass the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity and create an IntentFilter for it which matches your callbackUrl.
This is how I am getting my tokens
authenticationResult = await authenticationService.LoginAsync(new {
                        audience = Preferences.Get("Audience", https://xxx.abc.com/api"), // Audience from Auth0 portal
                        prompt = "<Insert prompt>"
                    });//.Authenticate();

                    if ((!authenticationResult?.IsError ?? false) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationResult?.AccessToken)) {
                        ToggleButtonAndTextVisibility(true, false);
                    }
                    if (authenticationResult != null && authenticationResult.AccessToken != null && !authenticationResult.IsError) {
                        // Save the access and the id bearer tokens to the user preferences store
                        Preferences.Set("AccessToken", authenticationResult?.AccessToken);
                        Preferences.Set("AccessTokenExpiration", authenticationResult?.AccessTokenExpiration.ToString("O"));
                        Preferences.Set("IdToken", authenticationResult?.IdentityToken);
                        Preferences.Set("RefreshToken", authenticationResult?.RefreshToken);
                        Preferences.Set("IsAuthenticated", "true");
                        Preferences.Set("RefreshTokenDateTimeTicks", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                        hasAuthorization = true;
                    }


According to your RedirectUri = "com.abc://callback/", you can try to change your IntentFilter as:
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
              DataPath = "/callback/",,
              DataScheme = "com.abc")]


Still the same exception

Did you set the callback uri with the WebAuthenticatorResult like the official document did? @apexpredator

Do I need to because I think I am getting my tokens this way, added them in the original post

But I can't see where did you declare the callback uri. You can read the official document about the Callback URLs and the Redirect users to callback URLs on the AllowList in the auth0. @apexpredator

In addition, you can ask for help in auth0 community. @apexpredator

I think it worked because I am not getting that exception but the app does not run after this piece of code now
authenticationResult = await authenticationService.LoginAsync(new {
audience = Preferences.Get("Audience", "https://xxx.abc.com/api"), // Audience from Auth0 portal
prompt = "select_account"
})
No exception, just gets stuck post the login page. I tried print statements before that code, prints before but not after

Did you mean you have fixed the exception about WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity? @apexpredator

Meant the exception does not show up when I use "/callback" instead of "callback" but it still does not work. The code gets stopped on that line now instead of showing me an exception.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT, Based on what you suggested: DataPath = "/callback/", DataScheme = "com.abc", it would have to be com.abc:///callback, I don't think that is correct
